# Passing go embedded struct to function

Tags: go

I have something like this:

```
type Foo struct{}
func NewFoo() *Foo { ... }

type Bar struct {
    *Foo
}
```

How can I pass an instance of Bar to a function that takes *Foo?

```
func DoStuff(f *Foo) {}

func main() {
    bar := Bar{NewFoo()}
    DoStuff(bar) // <- go doesn't like this, type mismatch
}
```

Is it possible to get the embedded structure and pass it to the function?

The only way I can get this to work is if I treated *Foo as a member of the structure and passed it as `bar.foo`. But this is kind of messy, is that the only way?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Anonymous fields can be addressed by the name of the embedded type:

```
type Foo struct{}

type Bar struct {
    *Foo
}

bar := Bar{&Foo{}}

func(f *Foo) {}(bar.Foo)
```

See the [Struct Types](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types) section in the language spec.